# Implementing role-based authorization in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I've been following this tutorial, which is great btw, and have one question.

http://www.larryullman.com/2010/01/07/custom-authentication-using-the-yii-framework/

I can access the role property like this, anywhere in my application code:

```
Yii::app()->user->role
```

but, what I'd really like to do is use the default controller authorization in my UserController:

```
/**
  * Specifies the access control rules.
  * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
  * @return array access control rules
  */
public function accessRules()
{  
  return array(
   array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
    'actions'=>array('*'),
    'users'=>array('@'),
    // Fails
    'roles'=>array(ModelConstantsRole::ADMIN),
    // Also Fails
    'expression'=>'(isset(Yii::app()->user->role) && (Yii::app()->user->role==ModelConstantsRole::ADMIN))',
   ),
   array('deny',  // deny all users
    'users'=>array('*'),
   ),
  );
}
```

It appears that the class that actually validates the rules defined in accessRules doesn't actually know anything about my role that I've assigned it.
CAccessControlFilter (for those of you who don't want to search for it for 40 minutes XD).

Any ideas on how I can make use of the accessRules method when I combine it with Larry's approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your code it looks like you want to apply this rule to all the actions, to do that you need to leave the actions array unspecified or empty array:

```
//empty actions
array('allow',  
'actions'=>array(),//array('*'),
...
)
```

Or unspecified:

```
array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
//'actions'=>array('*'),
...
)
```

This is already [documented in the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter) :

> array(
>     'allow',  // or 'deny'
>     // optional, list of action IDs (case insensitive) that this rule applies to
>     // if not specified, rule applies to all actions
>     'actions'=>array('edit', 'delete'),

Keep in mind that the roles array is again an array with role names, example:

```
'roles'=>array('role1','role2','role3')
```

Then you don't need the 'expression' as all that you are doing in there is already being done with the roles array.

Edit: After reading the tutorial you have linked, it seems that he has not implemented [RBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control). The `'roles'` option uses rbac, so it won't work without it. Hence you'll have to use the `'expression'` option instead, and your `'expression'` option looks fine.

Comment: If you need clarifications, or if my answer is incomplete for you, then please comment

Comment: read my edit, if you are not using rbac, then you can use the `expression` option instead of `roles`, and the expression you have defined looks fine. but you'll still need to remove/change your `action` option, as already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: This looks like a great answer, especially with the link to the docs about how there's no such thing as 'actions'=>array('*').  I'll check this out tomorrow morning when I'm back to my computer, and if everything works, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: Works like a charm! It surprises me there's no star for actions.

Comment: yeah, well that's how it works, if you want to know the idea behind it, check the source of [isActionMatched](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessRule#isActionMatched-detail) function, which will try and match the requested action with the actions in the rules array, you'll see why '*' doesn't work. Btw, did you also have to include `'expression'`? or did it work with `'roles'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try set actions correctly

```
array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
    'actions'=>array('view', 'delete', 'update'),
```

Comment: This doesn't replicate my situation.  You have only allowed access to three actions here, not all actions.

Comment: If U need all action, do not set 'actions'